# Reconhecer a cor de uma imagem em python

Tags: python, cores

Como parte do meu aprendizado em python, eu resolvi criar um programa simples que detecta a cor de uma imagem (cor sólida).
O problema é que eu não tenho ideia de como fazer isso, existe  alguma biblioteca em python que detecta a cor e dá o valor dela em RGB ou hex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das bibliotecas do Python para se trabalhar com imagem é a [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Com ela, é possível pegar as cores que aparecem em uma imagem.

```
from PIL import Image

# Abre a imagem
img = Image.open("Path/minhaImagem.jpg")
```

Depois de abrir uma imagem, é possível percorrer pixel a pixel com o [`.getdata()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=getdata#PIL.Image.Image.getdata) e ver a cor RGB de cada um. Se quiser saber apenas quais cores aparecem, basta guardar os valores únicos. Exemplo:

```
cores = []
for cor_rgb in img.getdata():
    if cor_rgb not in cores:
        cores.append(cor_rgb)

>>> print(cores)
   [(163, 78, 90), (158, 69, 88), (70, 44, 65), (38, 30, 48)]
```

Uma maneira mais fácil é usar o próprio [`.getcolors()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=getcolors#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors), que retorna tanto as cores quanto a quantidade em que elas aparecem. Ele tem um parâmetro `maxcolors`, que por padrão é 256 cores. Se o numero de cores da sua imagem passar do valor de `maxcolors`, a função retorna `None`.

```
>>> cores = img.convert('RGB').getcolors()
>>> print(cores)
   None

>>> cores = img.convert('RGB').getcolors(maxcolors=1000)
>>> print(cores)
   [(10, (163, 78, 90)), (1, (158, 69, 88)), ...]
#  [(quantidade, cor_rgb), (quantidade, cor_rgb),...]
```